# Trying to set state for individual todo items and have them maintain and toggle between 3 colors on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

They also must maintain their color after items are deleted (and thus re-arranged).
Currently, everything works except nothing happens when I click on each item.

I've spent over 20 hrs trying to get this to work and the closest I've come is to having it work perfectly other than after I delete an item the item below the deleted item takes on the color of the deleted item. I have changed my code up quite a bit since then, but at this point I'm completely baffled as to why it isn't updating the color. For some reason, it isn't making it past the first conditional in my handleClick(), even though the conditional is true (as far as I can tell).

This is really bothering me and at this point becoming a hindrance to my progress because it's so distracting. please help!

I signed up to stackOverflow just for this question (and perhaps the first of many).

Here is all the code that should be required to understand what I'm doing wrong. I can provide a github link to my repo if anyone requests it.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import Header from './components/layout/Header'

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    todos: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'click me',
        status: 'red',
      },
    ],
    input: '',
    counter: 2,
  }

  onChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ input: event.target.value })
  }

  onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.setState({
      todos: [
        ...this.state.todos,
        {
          title: this.state.input,
          id: this.state.counter,
          status: 'red',
        },
      ],
      input: '',
      counter: this.state.counter + 1,
    })
  }

  removeItem = (id) => {
    this.setState({
      todos: [...this.state.todos.filter((x, i) => i !== id)],
    })
  }

  handleClick = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      todos: this.state.todos.map((todo) => {
        if (todo.status === 'red' && todo.id === e.currentTarget.value) {
          todo.status = 'yellow'
        } else if (
          todo.status === 'yellow' &&
          todo.id === e.currentTarget.value
        ) {
          todo.status = 'green'
        } else if (
          todo.status === 'green' &&
          todo.id === e.currentTarget.value
        ) {
          todo.status = 'red'
        }
        return todo
      }),
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <form style={{ display: 'flex' }} onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="title"
            style={{ flex: '10', padding: '5px' }}
            placeholder="Add Todo ..."
            value={this.state.input}
            onChange={this.onChange}
          />
          <input
            type="submit"
            value="Submit"
            className="btn"
            style={{ flex: '1' }}
          />
        </form>

        <ul>
          {this.state.todos.map((todo, idx) => {
            return (
              <li key={todo.id}>
                <span
                  onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}
                  style={{ color: todo.status }}
                  value={todo.id}
                  id={idx}
                >
                  {todo.title}
                </span>
                <span>
                  <button onClick={() => this.removeItem(idx)}>X</button>
                </span>
              </li>
            )
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

Comment: Are you sure `e.currentTarget.value` is returning you the correct thing?

Comment: Also I'd be careful, you're mixing `todo.id` and `idx`. Use your key everywhere, don't use an index value; consider what would happen if you ever reordered your list.

Comment: It could also be because you're modifying the original value in your `.map`, React isn't picking up that the object has changed and therefore not causing a re-render. Try `return { ...todo, status: 'yellow' }` instead of `todo.status = 'yellow'`.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code that solved my problem:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import Header from './components/layout/Header'

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    todos: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'click me',
        status: 'red',
      },
    ],
    input: '',
    counter: 2,
  }

  onChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ input: event.target.value })
  }

  onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.setState({
      todos: [
        ...this.state.todos,
        {
          title: this.state.input,
          id: this.state.counter,
          status: 'red',
        },
      ],
      input: '',
      counter: this.state.counter + 1,
    })
  }

  removeItem = (id) => {
    this.setState({
      todos: [...this.state.todos.filter((x, i) => i !== id)],
    })
  }

  handleClick = (todo) => {
    if (todo.status === 'red') {
      console.log('clicked!')
      todo.status = 'yellow'
    } else if (todo.status === 'yellow') {
      todo.status = 'green'
    } else if (todo.status === 'green') {
      todo.status = 'red'
    }
    console.log(todo.status)

    this.setState({ todos: this.state.todos })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <form style={{ display: 'flex' }} onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="title"
            style={{ flex: '10', padding: '5px' }}
            placeholder="Add Todo ..."
            value={this.state.input}
            onChange={this.onChange}
          />
          <input
            type="submit"
            value="Submit"
            className="btn"
            style={{ flex: '1' }}
          />
        </form>

        <ul>
          {this.state.todos.map((todo, idx) => {
            return (
              <li key={todo.id}>
                <span
                  onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(todo)}
                  style={{ color: todo.status }}
                  value={todo.id}
                  id={idx}
                >
                  {todo.title}
                </span>
                <span>
                  <button onClick={() => this.removeItem(idx)}>X</button>
                </span>
              </li>
            )
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

i was able to have an experienced programmer walk me through it. i was toggling the `status` variable successfully between all 3 colors, but i was not updating state with setState and so it was not being tracked. i failed to realize that i was not allowing react to track the status change at the end of the eventListener.

thank you so much for your replies and so quickly! hope my ignorance helps someone else.